# The return value is undefined.Could tell what should I do to fix it?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, asynchronous, mean-stack

> The value of store is undefined.colud tell me what I did wrong.
> Should I use Async and await or Promise ?

```
var store = db.read(collectionName, (status, data) => {
        //database read function
        if (status) {
          names.listOfData = data;
          var send = names;
          console.log("send---->", send);     // send value here is what I need to return.
          return send;            // Getting required data for send. Problem here is returning it and storing it in store.
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      });
```

> console.log("store-->", store);

> Here value of store is Undefined. No proper return

Comment: Which module are you using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write a result to store and immediately see it there after `db.read` because `db.read` does not wait when a callback will be finished and does not return data from it as a return value.

You should wrap this call to `new Promise`. It may look like this:

```
var store = await (new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
  db.read(collectionName, (status, data) => {
        //database read function
        if (status) {
          names.listOfData = data;
          var send = names;
          console.log("send---->", send);     // send value here is what I need to return.
          resolve(send);
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      });
});
```

Please read more about asynchronous functions, `async/await`, `Promise` and how to convert a function with a callback into an async function.